# Поиск повторяющихся чисел в графе

Tags: java, алгоритм, graph

Дан массив A длины (n+1),  содержащий натуральные числа от 1 до n. Найти любой повторяющийся элемент за время O(n), не изменяя массив и не используя дополнительной памяти.

```
public class Graph{
    private final int MAX_VERTS = 9;
    public Vertex vertexList[]; // Список вершин
    private int adjMat[][]; // Матрица смежности
    private int nVerts; // Текущее количество вершин
    private StackX theStackX;

    public Graph(){
        vertexList = new Vertex[MAX_VERTS];
        adjMat = new int[MAX_VERTS][MAX_VERTS];
        nVerts = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VERTS; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < MAX_VERTS; j++)
                adjMat[i][j] = 0;
            theStackX = new StackX();

    }



    // Метод возвращает непосещенную вершину, смежную по отношению к v
    public int getUnvisitedVertex(int v){
        for (int i = 0; i < nVerts; i++) {
            if (adjMat[v][i] == 1 && vertexList[i].wasVisited == false)
                return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    // обход в глубину
    public void dfs(){
        vertexList[0].wasVisited = true;
        displayVertex(0);
        theStackX.push(0);

        while (!theStackX.isEmpty()){
            int v = getUnvisitedVertex(theStackX.peek());

            if (v == -1)
                theStackX.pop();
            else{
                vertexList[v].wasVisited = true;
                displayVertex(v);
                theStackX.push(v);
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(c);
        // Стек пуст, работа закончена
        for (int i = 0; i < nVerts; i++) {
            vertexList[i].wasVisited = false;
        }
    }

    // Добавляем вершину
    public void addVertex(int val){
        vertexList[nVerts++] = new Vertex(val);
    }

    // Добавляем края
    public void addEdge(int start, int end){
        adjMat[start][end] = 1;
        adjMat[end][start] = 1;
    }

    public void displayVertex(int v){
        System.out.print(vertexList[v].value + " ");

    }
}


public class Vertex {
    public int value;
    public boolean wasVisited;

    public Vertex(int value){
        this.value = value;
        wasVisited = false;
    }
}


public class StackX {
    private final int SIZE = 20;
    private int[] st;
    private int top;

    public StackX(){
        st = new int[SIZE];
        top = -1;
    }

    // Размещение элемента в стеке
    public void push(int j){
        st[++top] = j;
    }

    // Извлечение элемента из стека
    public int pop(){
        return st[top--];
    }

    // Чтение с вершины стека
    public int peek(){
        return st[top];
    }

    // Если стек пуст
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return top == -1;
    }
}


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Runner {
    private static ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graph theGraph = new Graph();

        theGraph.addVertex(3);
        theGraph.addVertex(5);
        theGraph.addVertex(3);
        theGraph.addVertex(10);
        theGraph.addVertex(7);
        theGraph.addVertex(4);
        theGraph.addVertex(0);
        theGraph.addVertex(2);
        theGraph.addVertex(4);

        theGraph.addEdge(0, 1);
        theGraph.addEdge(1, 2);
        theGraph.addEdge(2, 3);
        theGraph.addEdge(3, 4);
        theGraph.addEdge(4, 5);
        theGraph.addEdge(4, 6);
        theGraph.addEdge(4, 7);
        theGraph.addEdge(4, 8);


        System.out.println("Visits: ");
        theGraph.dfs();
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Посещаю все вершины, но не знаю как находить повторяющиеся числа.

Comment: вы просто скопировали код из книги. тут ничего от вас нет. (Лафаре. Структуры данных)

Comment: Раз уж вы работаете по статье - то там алгоритм был описан более чем детально. Граф там - понятие вспомогательное, для пояснения работы алгоритма, а не для вычислений...

Comment: Все числа от 1 до n или это просто ограничение? И графы тут не при чём.